# Check if all elements of a list start with all the different symbols of another list python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

My question is, how do you check if all of the elements of a list start with all the diffrents symbols of another list ? i tried the code bellow

```
# List1
List1 = ['#%ffffff','#csssssss','#tssssssss','#*ssss','#indexqqqqqq']

# List2
List2 = ['#%','#c','#t','#*','#index','#!']
check  = all (ele for ele in List1 if ele.startswith(tuple(List2)))
if check is True:
     print("The list {} contains all elements of the list {}".format(List1, List2))    
else :
     print("No, List1 doesn't have all elements of the List2.")
```

But it returns always True, any suggestions ?

Comment: You mean `all(ele.startswith(tuple(List2)) for ele in List1)`

Comment: Also it's better just `if check:`

Comment: why convert List2 to a tuple for each element of List1

Comment: @rioV8 because i got this error while using it as a list:  startswith first arg must be str or a tuple of str, not list

Comment: the important part of the comment is `for each element`

Comment: @rioV8 Yes each element of List2 must exist in the List1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Yes each element of List2 must exist in the List1

As this is a requirement for your code, you might have to use something like this.

```
# List1
List1 = ['#%ffffff','#csssssss','#tssssssss','#*ssss','#indexqqqqqq']

# List2
List2 = ['#%','#c','#t','#*','#index','#!']

founds = []

for elem2 in List2:
    found = False
    for elem1 in List1:
        if elem1.startswith(elem2):
            found = True
    founds.append(found)

check  = all(founds)



if check is True:
     print("The list {} contains all elements of the list {}".format(List1, List2))    
else :
     print("No, List2 doesn't have all elements of the List1.")
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work.

```
List1 = ['%ffffff','csssssss','tssssssss','*ssss','indexqqqqqq']

# List2
List2 = ['#%','#c','#t','#*','#index','#!']
check = all(ele.startswith(tuple(List2)) for ele in List1)

if check is True:
    print("The list {} contains all elements of the list {}".format(List1, List2))
else:
    print("No, List1 doesn't have all elements of the List2.")
```